# Ui:style or css class in GWT/UiBinder

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

What is more preferable to use `<ui:style>` or write `class` in `css` file for `HTML` elements (for `GWT Widgets`) in `GWT ui.xml` file. I know that if to use `<ui:style>` so the `class` attribute has very difficult name. Help me please  find out when to use `<ui:style>`

```
<ui:style>
   .panel {
        width: 100%;
   }
   .decPanel {
        height:100%;
   }
</ui:style>

<g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames='{style.panel}'>
    <fieldset addStyleNames='{style.decPanel}'>
        <legend>
            ...
        </legend>
    </fieldset>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

and when to use `class`

**CSS** file

```
   .panel {
        width: 100%;
   }
   .decPanel {
        height:100%;
   }
```

**ui.xml** file

```
<g:HTMLPanel class="panel">
   <fieldset class="decPanel">
        <legend>
            ...
        </legend>
   </fieldset>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705553/gwt-uibinder-css-styling may solve your solution

Comment: @AnilBhattarai100 Thanks, but it's not quite what I had in mind. I've added some examples in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help you to understand the advantage of using `<ui:style>` over constant static class name.

#### [Hello Stylish World](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World)

With the `<ui:style>` element, you can define the CSS for your UI right where you need it.

Sample:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'>

    <ui:style>
      .pretty { background-color: Skyblue; }
    </ui:style>

    <div class='{style.pretty}'>
      Hello, <span ui:field='nameSpan'/>.
    </div>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

#### Advantage

- A [CssResource](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.html) interface is generated for you, along with a [ClientBundle](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/ClientBundle.html). This means that the compiler will warn you if you **misspell the class name** when you try to use it (e.g. `{style.prettty}`).
- Also, your CSS class name will be **obfuscated**, thus protecting it from **collision with like class names** in other CSS blocks—no more global CSS namespace!

---

**Note:** Most real world projects will probably keep their CSS in a separate file. In the example given below, the src values are relative to the location of the ui.xml file.

Sample

```
  <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'>
    <ui:style src="MyUi.css" />
    <ui:style field='otherStyle' src="MyUiOtherStyle.css">

    <div class='{style.pretty}'>
      Hello, <span class='{otherStyle.pretty}' ui:field='nameSpan'/>.
    </div>
  </ui:UiBinder>
```

Prefer `<span class='{otherStyle.pretty}'` instead of `<span class='pretty'`.

======================

**EDIT**

As per suggestion by @Thomas in comments, prefer to use `<ui:with>`

Sometimes your template will need to work with styles or other objects that come from outside of your template. Use the `<ui:with>` element to make them available.

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

  <ui:with field='res' type='com.my.app.widgets.logoname.Resources'/>

  <g:HTMLPanel>

    <g:Image resource='{res.logo}'/>

    <div class='{res.style.mainBlock}'>
      <div class='{res.style.userPictureSprite}'/>

      <div>
        Well hello there
        <span class='{res.style.nameSpan}' ui:field='nameSpan'/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>

/**
 * Resources used by the entire application.
 */
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
  @Source("Style.css")
  Style style();

  @Source("Logo.jpg")
  ImageResource logo();

  public interface Style extends CssResource {
    String mainBlock();
    String nameSpan();
    Sprite userPictureSprite();
  }
}
// Within the owner class for the UiBinder template
@UiField Resources res;

...

res.style().ensureInjected();
```

Refer GWT documentation on [Using an external resource](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html)

Comment: +1, except I disagree with the last note: using `src=` that way means a single CSS source will probably be used by several implicit `CssResource`s, each with its own obfuscated names. `src=` is good for importing constants (combined with `<ui:style>` content); otherwise use an explicit `ClientBundle`+`CssResource` and import it with `<ui:with>`.